# How to ignore RSpec::ExampleGroups::EmptyContentValidation error on compiling a null value in JSON?

Tags: ruby, rspec

Here is what I get:

```
*** NameError Exception: undefined local variable or method `null' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::EmptyContentValidation:0x00007fdd2d2775d8>
```

Here is what I have as code:

```
actual =
        {
            "posts": [
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "title": "Post 3"
                }
            ],
            "profile": {
                "name": ""
            },
            "nulldata": {
                "res": null
            }
        }
```

[image]

1. Not sure why `RSpec::ExampleGroups::EmptyContentValidation` is
   thrown when the above json snippet is compiled
2. How to get rid of this error message (or to turn off this error which is not relevant)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That isn't JSON, that's a Ruby hash. And in Ruby there is no `null`, instead you use `nil`. You can confirm all of this by pasting into your REPL:

```
actual =
        {
            "posts": [
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "title": "Post 3"
                }
            ],
            "profile": {
                "name": ""
            },
            "nulldata": {
                "res": null
            }
        }
```

This will return:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `null' for main:Object
```

Now change it to `nil`:

```
actual =
        {
            "posts": [
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "title": "Post 3"
                }
            ],
            "profile": {
                "name": ""
            },
            "nulldata": {
                "res": nil
            }
        }
```

This will return:

```
=> {
       :posts => [
        [0] {
               :id => 3,
            :title => "Post 3"
        }
    ],
     :profile => {
        :name => ""
    },
    :nulldata => {
        :res => nil
    }
}
```

And you can even confirm that it's not JSON (which is a `String`) but is instead a `Hash`:

```
actual.class
=> Hash < Object
```